# Find out computer's total free RAM from web browser

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, memory-management, browser

Is there a way to find out the total amount of available (free) RAM on a computer via the web browser or flash?

Comment: Why would you think I'd like a website to get more details of my computer?  They get more than I like in the HTTP header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in Flash or JavaScript. The best you can do in Flash is see how much RAM is in *use* by the player ([flash.system.System.totalMemory](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/System.html#totalMemory)).

Java allows you to get a bit more information about free memory ([Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory%28%29)), but that is still only memory available to the VM, not necessarily the system as a whole.

Comment: If you're targetting player 10.1, you also have System.freeMemory, however that only returns the free memory left in the current page of memory that flash has grabbed (it grabs them in 1MB pages I think)